# Select at most n(in my case 2) rows in jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to select at most two rows in a jtable at a time.
I am using 
`table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);` 
as selection model.

If more than 2 rows are selected then, the last selected row should be replaced with newly selected rows.

Thanks for your help :)

### UPDATE : Code which works after implementing the suggestions

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class TestLimitedMultiSelectTable {

private int limit = 2;
private String[] columns = new String[] { "Id", "Name", "Hourly Rate",
        "Part Time" };

// actual data for the table in a 2d array
private Object[][] data = new Object[][] { { 1, "John", 40.0, false },
        { 2, "Rambo", 70.0, false }, { 3, "Zorro", 60.0, true },
        { 4, "Zorro", 60.0, true }, { 5, "Zorro", 60.0, true },
        { 6, "Zorro", 60.0, true }, };

private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
private JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);
private JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);

public TestLimitedMultiSelectTable() {
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(pane);
    table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

    table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

    table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(
            new ListSelectionListener() {

                @Override
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                    ListSelectionModel selectionModel = table
                            .getSelectionModel();

                    int[] selectedRows = table.getSelectedRows();

                    if (selectedRows.length > limit) {
                        selectionModel.removeSelectionInterval(
                                selectionModel.getLeadSelectionIndex(),
                                selectionModel.getLeadSelectionIndex());
                        selectedRows = table.getSelectedRows();
                        for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
                            System.out.println(selectedRows[i]);
                        }

                    }

                }
            });
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestLimitedMultiSelectTable();
}

}
```

Comment: You might have to implement your own `ListSelectionModel`.

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE / MCVE, short, runnable, compilable,with hardcoded value for JTable / XxxTableModel in local variable

Comment: Thank you guys for suggestions. I was able to get a solution.
Adding code which does the job.